# Dynamically allocated int Array in C input via terminal

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic

I am new to C and I was trying to code up a dynamic int array that lets the user type in numbers via terminal untill the user types in -1. So the user can type any amount of int's and the data is reallocated each time another valid int is input.

Sometimes it works as expected other times I get: **free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)** error.
I am printing the values after every input and everything seems fine untill -1 is input. And the bug only occures every other time.

Here is my Code:

```
void output(int *ptr, int len){
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("%d %p \n", ptr[i], ptr+i);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int input(int *ptr, int *size){

    int x;

    printf("Insert your numbers:\n");
    while(1){

        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(x == -1) break;

        size[0]++;
        // printf("Size: %d\n", size[0]);
        ptr = realloc(ptr, size[0] * sizeof(int));
        if(ptr == NULL) return -1;
        int indexToStore = size[0]-1;
        // printf("Index: %d\n", indexToStore);
        ptr[indexToStore] = x;
        output(ptr, size[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int *array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL) return -1;

    input(array, &size);
    output(array, size);
    input(array, &size);
    output(array, size);

    free(array); array = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding the statement `int indexToStore = size[0]-1;`  on the first call to `input()` the value in `size` is 0,  so `size[0]-1` becomes 0xFFFFFFFF (-1) so `indexToStore` become -1.  The result is  undefined behavior in the statement:  `ptr[indexToStore] = x;`  Also, the function: `output()` is called twice for each call to `input()`, which is probably not what you want

Comment: every time the function: `input()` is called, another memory leak is created.  This because the pointer  `array[]` in `main()` is never updated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `ptr` of the function `input` is *a copy of* what is passed and modifying that will not affect what is passed in caller.

Therefore, the change in buffer via `realloc()` is not saved from the 1st call of `input()` to the 2nd call of `input()` and it will lead to troubles.

You should pass a pointer to what should be modified to have functions modify caller's local things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void output(int *ptr, int len){
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("%d %p \n", ptr[i], ptr+i);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int input(int **ptr, int *size){

    int x;

    printf("Insert your numbers:\n");
    while(1){

        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(x == -1) break;

        size[0]++;
        // printf("Size: %d\n", size[0]);
        *ptr = realloc(*ptr, size[0] * sizeof(int));
        if(*ptr == NULL) return -1;
        int indexToStore = size[0]-1;
        // printf("Index: %d\n", indexToStore);
        (*ptr)[indexToStore] = x;
        output(*ptr, size[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int *array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL) return -1;

    input(&array, &size);
    output(array, size);
    input(&array, &size);
    output(array, size);

    free(array); array = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```